# How to get sub 10ms response times from AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In the DynamoDB documentation and in many places around the internet I've seen that single digit ms response times are typical, but I cannot seem to achieve that even with the simplest setup.  I have configured a t2.micro ec2 instance and a DynamoDB table, both in us-west-2, and when running the command below from the aws cli on the ec2 instance I get responses averaging about 250 ms.  The same command run from my local machine (Denver) averages about 700 ms.

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name my-table --key file://key.json
```

When looking at the CloudWatch metrics in the AWS console it says the average get latency is 12 ms though.  If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the direction of information where I can solve this on my own I would really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cloudwatch metrics are showing the time taken by DDB itself in processing your query. That is 12ms. 250 or 700ms that you are seeing at your machine side would be due to network travel, service discovery, credential matching etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The response times you are seeing are largely do to the cold start times of the aws cli. When running your get-item command the cli has to get loaded into memory, fetch  temporary credentials (if using an ec2 iam role when running on your t2.micro instance), and establish a secure connection to the DynamoDB service. After all that is completed then it executes the get-item request and finally prints the results to stdout. Your command is also introducing a need to read the key.json file off the filesystem, which adds additional overhead.

My experience running on a t2.micro instance is the aws cli has around 200ms of overhead when it starts, which seems inline with what you are seeing.

This will not be an issue with long running programs, as they only pay a similar overhead price at start time. I run a number of web services on t2.micro instances which work with DynamoDB and the DynamoDB response times are consistently sub 20ms.

Comment: I created a restify.js server on the t2.micro and it performed exactly inline with AWS docs and what you've said here.  Thanks a lot! And keep up the great work on vogels, I'm loving it so far!

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of factors that go into the latency you will see when making a REST API call. DynamoDB can provide latencies in the single digit milliseconds but there are some caveats and things you can do to minimize the latency.

The first thing to consider is distance and speed of light.  Expect to get the best latency when accessing DynamoDB when you are using an EC2 instance located in the same region.  It is normal to see higher latencies when accessing DynamoDB from your laptop or another data center.  Note that each region also has multiple data centers.

There are also performance costs from the client side based on the hardware, network connection, and programming language that you are using.  When you are talking millisecond latencies the processing time on your machine can make a difference.

Another likely source of the latency will be the TLS handshake.  Establishing an encrypted connection requires multiple round trips and computation on both sides to get the encrypted channel established.  However, as long as you are using a Keep Alive for the connection you will only pay this overheard for the first query.  Successive queries will be substantially faster since they do not incur this initial penalty.  Unfortunately the AWS CLI isn't going to keep the connection alive between requests, but the AWS SDKs for most languages will manage this for you automatically.

---

Another important consideration is that the latency that DynamoDB reports in the web console is the average.  While DynamoDB does provide reliable *average* low double digit latency, the maximum latency will regularly be in the hundreds of milliseconds or even higher.  This is visible by viewing the maximum latency in CloudWatch.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was very helpful in conjunction with ryan's answer.

Comment: The overhead of loading AWS credentials from a role is another startup cost that I failed to mention in my answer that Ryan included. The bottom line is there is a warmup period before your requests execute at full speed.

Answer (score 5):

They recently announced DAX (Preview).
Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) is a fully managed, highly available, in-memory cache for DynamoDB that delivers up to a 10x performance improvement – from milliseconds to microseconds – even at millions of requests per second. For more information, see [In-Memory Acceleration with DAX (Preview)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.html).

Comment: DAX is now generally available.